# replying to tweet with image using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

i'm trying to tweepy to reply to certain tweets, and my reply includes an image.
the *twt* variable holds the tweet i'm trying to reply to.
here's what i'm doing at the moment:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tweepy, time, random  

CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXX'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXXX'
ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXX'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'XXXX'  

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)  

query = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
t0 = time.time()
count = 0
last_count = 0

f = open('last_replied.txt')
last_replied = int(f.readline().strip())
f.close()
print('starting time:', time.strftime('%X'))

while True:
    if count > last_count:
        print(time.strftime('%X'), ':', count, 'replies')
        last_count = count
    for i in range(3):
        twts = api.search(query[i], since_id=last_replied)
        if len(twts)>0:
            for twt in twts:
                sid = twt.id
                sn = twt.user.screen_name
                stat = "lalala" + "@" + sn
                api.update_with_media('oscar1.gif',status=stat,in_reply_to_status_id=sid)
                count += 1
                last_replied = twt.id
                f = open('last_replied.txt','w')
                f.write(str(last_replied))
                f.close()
        pause = random.randint(50,90)
        time.sleep(pause)
```

my tweet gets posted, but not as a reply to the original tweet (*twt*). instead, it just gets posted as a new, independent, tweet.
however, when instead of update_with_media as above, i use update_status, such as:

```
api.update_status(status=stat,in_reply_to_status_id=sid)
```

my new tweet does get posted as a reply to the original tweet (*twt*).

what am i missing?
thanks

Comment: Here is some code reply to a tweet with api.update_with_media and works correctly, maybe looking at some code help you :) https://github.com/Soben713/Twizhoosh/blob/master/scripts/twitter_related/mustachify/mustachify.py

Comment: @Mohammadalibaghershemirani i believe you're using some other module, not tweepy like me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution i ended up with was switching to the `twython` module, that has the functionality well documented and working perfectly.
thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The update_with_media endpoint is being deprecated by Twitter (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update_with_media) you shouldn't use it. Instead upload the media first with the media_upload method and add the media_ids you get back to the update_status method.

Comment: thank you, Juan.
do you know if there's a python library that supports those functions? it seems tweepy doesn't (or at least they don't mention anything about that in their documentation)

Comment: the twython wrapper seems to have this new functionality. thanks!

Comment: @teknoboy as I mentioned in my answer Tweepy has the media_upload method that you could have used.

Comment: i'm quite the novice programmer, and felt more at ease with twython's (better) documentation.  
thank you very much, you set me on the right path.

Comment: @JuanE. Is there any documentation or examples on how to us the media_upload method in Tweepy? I can't find anything.

Comment: I tested uploading image first and then updating status, but I could not reply to origin tweet... I hope someone finds a solution to this problem using tweedy.

Answer (score 0):

I glanced at the code for update_with_media and don't see any obvious bugs, but the new method of handling tweets with media was added to the Tweepy API in January - note the last two bullets here:

https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v3.2.0

If you download Tweepy 3.2.0 you should be able to switch over to the new regimen, which will hopefully fix your reply_to problem. (I can't say for sure if the new stuff works, I'm using an older version of Tweepy myself.)